# Prevent IndexedDb from growing exponentially in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I wanted to try IndexedDB, to see if it is fit for my purpose.
Doing some testing, I noticed, that its grow rate seems to be exponentially with every insert.

(Only tested in google chrome version 31.0.1650.63 (Offizieller Build 238485) m / Windows by now)

My Code in full: http://pastebin.com/15WK96FY

Basically I save a string with 2.6 mio characters.
Checking `window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota` I see that it consumes ~7.8MB, meaning ~3 bytes per character used.

If I save the string 10 times however, I get a usage of ~167MB, meaning ~6.4 bytes per character used.

By saving it 50 times I'm high up in the gigabytes and my computer starts to freeze.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a way around this behaviour?

Comment: is quota the same as usage?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#query It gives the amount used, including metadata, etc. in bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is wrong. Field `test2` should not be indexed.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to figure out what you meant there. Thought I would define which values would be stored, when saving an object, much like columns in mysql. Turns out it saves all anyways. Another thing that helps a lot is, to wait until one transaction completed before starting the next one. (Right now I'm creating all transactions at once, they get only executed after the loop [in idle])

Comment: Right. There is only one write tx per scope. You should make multiple requests in a transaction, and see how fast they are.